# Linux command that can do this Batch Command's job

Tags: linux, batch-file, command

I have a batch command:

```
deploy_package.cmd -f ../../packages -s %TargetSystem%
```

I need a linux command which can do the same task of the above batch command. I have `deploy_package.sh` available in the same location.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
./deploy_package.sh -f ../../packages -s $TargetSystem
```

Instead of the variable `$TargetSystem` you should write the name of the Target System (if the variable does not exist; and it does not exist, of course).

Information about your system (type, architecture and so on) you can get using `uname`.